# логика приложения используя JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Объясните логику написания приложения используя JavaFX.
Суть у меня такая: есть три FXML файла **mainWindows**, **Windows2** - которое открывается используя **Button2**, и **Windows3** - которое открывается **Buttonn3**. Как я понял каждому FXML файлу должен принадлежать свой класс контроллер, но контроллер mainController использует как минимум два метода для открытия окон (использует FXML **Windows2** и **Windows3**), получается так, что этим FXML файлам должен принадлежать один контроллер, и вопрос заключается в том, правильно ли это? Ведь как я слышал каждому FXML должен принадлежать свой контроллер, но в таком случае как реализовать логику? Ведь FXML файлу необходимо привязывать контроллер

Answer (score 0):

Все три контроллера живут отдельно.
В классе Main , аналогично методу public void start, который запускает window1, нужно создать методы public void showWindow2() и public void showWindow3(), которые будут запускать окна 2 и 3.
public void start запускается автоматически при старте программы методом launch

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
}
```

А методы запуска окон 2 и 3 нужно вызывать из контроллера первого окна (по нажатию кнопки).